# jQuery imitate #anchor click

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, anchor

I'm working on a site with a accordion list. I want the viewport to "scroll" to the clicked accordion, so the list starts here.

I can achieve this by setting `href="#accordion-id"` but I then have to ID all the accordion list elements on the whole site.

Is there any way to imitate the #anchor click with jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by finding the elements position with some code like this:

```
var item = $("#accordion-item").position();
$(window).scrollTop(item.top);
```

In fairness, you're probably going to need ID tags either way if you want a unique movement for each accordion item. Hope this helps